# In which cases do you need to implement these complex token authentication on devise (Rails 3.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, devise

I'm building a Rails app on Heroku.

I installed devise to manage user authentication on which I wanted to add "token authenticatable".

I basically used [this tutorial](http://codedecoder.wordpress.com/2013/01/08/devise-login-with-authentication_token/) and it works great

However, I ran across more complex tutorial about token authenticatable like these two ones:

- http://matteomelani.wordpress.com/2011/10/17/authentication-for-mobile-devices/
- http://mojoware.com/posts/mobile-rails-api-with-devise

I don't understand why they get much more complex than what I implemented? They seem to mention "mobile" stuff so does that mean it's a more complex way to use "token authenticatable" because it allows to authenticate in more cases of use such as on mobile?

Really in the dark so I appreciate any help.

Comment: Actually in last two articles authors just gave more explanation about building API's via devise & token_authenticatable module. In fact there is no difference between using token authentication for desktop and mobile clients

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the most part, authentication in a (native) mobile app works pretty much the same way as authentication through a browser: the user gives his credentials, these are sent over the wire to the server/app, and the app responds by giving the user a 'token' representing an authenticated session.

The main differences: browser-based clients will generally submit said credentials using HTTP POST of an HTML form, using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. The returned token is usually given as a session cookie, which the browser presents with every subsequent HTTP request.

Native mobile clients, on the other hand, while functioning as the browser *aren't* restricted to the HTML way of doing things, and most of them don't use cookies.

The typical mobile client uses a Web service *API*. Most APIs are designed to be as *stateless* as possible (unlike browser/cookie-based sessions).

Most Web service APIs also need/want to be able to send & receive as much hierarchical, complex data as possible, using as little bandwidth as possible. Hence, they favor more compact representations of structured data such as [JSON](http://www.json.org/) (or in some cases, [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/)).

In most cases, as well, it is undesirable to present the authentication token as a URL query parameter (or, if you're sending over a JSON payload you might as well include the token in there).

For that reason, the stock Devise session controller and token authentication mechanism is inadequate, and hence numerous examples of how to provide alternative, REST-ful or JSON-based authentication that extends Devise.